# Performance effect on field length

Tags: entities, performance

When we are adding a text field to a content type the default length is 255. I am curious to know the performance effect of the field types and the length have for it.

Is there a preferred order of fields and length based on performance? so that we can chose our fields accordingly.

Comment: I'm no performance expert, but eh, I doubt it. It's more for how many letters/numbers/characters you want to allow for the field. For Example: 255  characters is overkill for a person's age or last name field. You don't want people putting funny long stuff there.

Comment: In my opinion the performance impace is minor vs. the maintainability of the field in case you chose length of 10 characters and one year later you'll want ir to change (you can't change the length after the field was created because it requires the DB table to change)

Answer (score 1):

Going over 255 means that field can not easily be indexed and thus if you filter on it in views or in a query it will be slow. As long as you stay below this limit all is well.